# Update a portion of Table in Excel from SQL table

Tags: c#, sql, sharepoint, excel, vba

I have requirement in which i have to update a portion of table in a sheet in Excel 2010 from SQL database server, but that excel workbook will not have the permission to access the database. For this i have to route that data from SQL to a SharePoint site which can be accessed by that excel workbook . 
Can you please tell me how can i update or connect live the SharePoint site to a excel workbook or is there any other options available to implement my requirement like excel vba or web services?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you really want to do is to create a data connection in Excel to the SharePoint list with the changes, then compare the new data to what is already in Excel and then use VBA to loop through the data you can either

1. Using VBA, update the existing data by comparing it to the new data
2. Using VBA, target the SharePoint Web Services to push changes to SharePoint